# Do you need a HDD with a sensor?

Tags: hard-drive, data-loss-prevention, physical-environment

I searched for HDDs and found out that they can have sensors, related to "shake" and other events, that ensure that stuff doesn't break.

My question is, if or when do you need an HDD with sensors, to ensure it doesn't break, well I'm not sure if it was designed for that, this entire sensor thing.

Sensors that I've heard so far from were, free fall sensors and rotational vibration sensors.

As example, if I would sometimes in a monthly delay or more, need to carry and move my PC around, should I better get one with a sensor or not?

I see these Seagate BarraCuda Compute HDD that claim to be a good "Laptop-PC" or "mobile" HDD, but apperantly it doesn't have any sensor, well I couldn't find information of it having a sensor. So I was wondering if it is actually still a good "mobile" HDD.

Comment: What you are talking about is HDD active protection that parks the heads when the drive is moved or shaken. That is a good thing to have for a HDD.  However time has move on, and Hard Drives have generally seen their day.  Perhaps consider using SSD drives instead. Faster and impervious to moves.

Comment: @John Yeah but it's about data but I mean, idk apperantly there's still a use for HDDs.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is HDD active protection that parks the heads when the drive is moved or shaken. That is a good thing to have for a HDD. I have use such drives. If you are buying a HDD, make sure it has this feature.

However time has moved on, and Hard Drives have generally seen their day. Perhaps consider using SSD drives instead (even for data storage). Faster and impervious to moves and shakes.

Comment: Yeah, but 6TB SSD is expensive. I specifically asked this question for HDD for a reason, related to sensors.

Comment: Yes, I understand. So get the drive with the Active Protection. I got two 2 TB SSD drives for my desktop computer and pricing was reasonable and now I do not have to worry about moving the computer

Comment: But how does a Seagate BarraCuda Compute HDD say it is good for laptop-pc, without it mentioning having a sensor? Does it have one or not?

Comment: It does not have to be but I do like Active Protection

Comment: The Seagate page says two year warranty but avoids saying the drive has active protection so I assume not.

Comment: So is a Toshiba X300 which mentions it has a sensor better? Also is CMR good? I mean all works similar.

Comment: It is now down to the drive you like best at this point.

Comment: Regarding to external HDDs, do all of them have sensors or is it also something that has to be looked at?

Comment: I cannot answer that with any authority. You need to look at each one you are considering purchasing.